# Windows Explorer like with QVFS in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, filesystems, virtual

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21329/QVFS-A-FAT32-Based-Virtual-File-System-Powered-by

I am using that code to create a Windows Explorer like application that uses a virtual file system.

The problem is that while I can click "Add" and simply add files to the virtual FS, I am unable to create directories. I am looking for a Windows Explorer type functionality, so I add a new folder, and when I double click it in the listview, it opens to a new page with the files in that directory.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You would have to modify the GUI in the example code presented in that article.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I mean, what do you mean I have to modify the GUI, or in what way do I need to modify?

Comment: If you have a look in the code for the test project, directory enumeration is already built in to the GUI. You need to add a button that lets you create directories. Look in the code that manages the virtual file system for the right functions to call, and then work out a way to drive those functions from a GUI. HTH.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I looked at the function and I triedusing it before asking it here, but I am clueless right now. Any help would help.

Comment: Also, I did call `CreateVDirectory()`, but what I need help on is adding the new directory to the listview and having the ability to browse through it (go inside it and look at files (if any) in there.)

Comment: It looks like the GUI test program has the functionality built in for that, but just isn't triggering it. Take a look at how the `GetDirs` function is used in the `btnOpen_Click` function. You just need to trigger `GetDirs` in the same way from your own application. Good luck!

Comment: Another open-source? He-he ...